# Allow all attributes in bootstrap wysihtml5 editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I want to add different custom attributes into the html view of my bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor. but they are stripped by default perserRules.

So is there any simple perserRule to allow all my custom attributes?

**Update**

What I am currently doing is:

```
tags: {
       "input": {
                "check_attributes": {
                    "class": "alt",
                    "type": "alt",
                    "fieldvalue": "alt",
                    "fieldname": "alt"
                 }
       },
       "textarea": {
                "check_attributes": {
                    "class": "alt",
                    "fieldtitle": "alt",
                    "fieldname": "alt"
                 }
       },
....}
```

like this way.
And what I need is like,

```
tags: {
       "input": {
                "*":"alt"
       },
       "textarea": {
                "*":"alt"
       },
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This? https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Answer (score 0):

It's currently impossible. `bootstrap-wysihtml5` doesn't have that option. You can [open an issue](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/issues/new) to request new feature.